# How much memory can an iPhone app use?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can anyone link me to a page that describes memory allocations for iPhone apps.

I have heard that you are limited to a sandbox of ~20 megs, depending on the state of the phone, but I can't find the source for this.

Comment: From what I've read you start getting memory warnings after **3MB**.  But I can't find any references back to apple either.

Comment: That hasn't been my experience. We don't really get memory warnings until we hit the teens. Our app runs in anywhere from 1.8-5 megs, and it spikes when we take photos.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on the device you're using. I've found that with an iPhone 3G, when the total memory your app is using goes over 10-14MB, it's vulnerable to crashing. When it hits 20MB, it will crash for sure.

As far as I know, Apple doesn't give any hard figures for the memory that you can use. It's always changing so it's hard to pin down. They recommend that you rely on memory warnings and respond to them appropriately.

iPhone 3GS has a much higher amount of memory available to apps (I've heard that it's around 4 times). Although the iPhone 3GS only has double the memory of the iPhone 3G, a lot of that memory is taken up by the OS. There's very little left for apps to run in. That's why the 3GS will allow apps to use so much more memory.

Also, there can be a lot of memory already in use by the OS. One example is when safari is keeping a lot of tabs open. This is why lots of games recommend that you restart the device if it crashes a lot.

When you're programming, keep an eye on the increase of memory (due to not properly deallocating objects) and the peak memory. This problem is more about real-world testing (on as many devices as possible) and good programming practices.

Here's an article to ready more about how to deal with memory problems:

http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/

Comment: The Safari thing is just hearsay, I've never tested it myself. Have you found that it's not true?

Comment: @nevanking but in case of ARC (automatic reference counting) should we worry about memory usage means about deallocating objects?

Answer (score 1):

This tool finds what is the maximum memory capacity of any iOS device. It also can also find at which memory level you received the Low Memory warning.

here is the link: https://github.com/Split82/iOSMemoryBudgetTest

Answer (score 0):

It depends on current device state. Some native iPhone applications can run in background and waste device resources(Mail, Safari, Sms, Phone...) So, it's hard to say how much memory u will get...Ideally, your application should stay within 10-12Mb limit to successfully overcome any memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's

- Memory warnings at 20MB
- Application "crashes" at 30MB

I'm fairly certain I saw this in [The iPhone Developer's Cookbook: Building Applications with the iPhone SDK by Erica Sadun](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321555457) (amazing book, btw).

Also: [Duplicate -> Maximum runtime memory available in iPhone and iPod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481908/maximum-runtime-memory-available-in-iphone-and-ipod).

Comment: I didn't mean to imply those were scientific fact. As a below poster wrote "I've found that with an iPhone 3G, when the total memory your app is using goes over 10-14MB, it's vulnerable to crashing. When it hits 20MB, it will crash for sure." These kind of are hard numbers when you think about it.